# Get Bootstrap 5 grid row to span its entire content vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How can I get a **Bootstrap 5** grid row to span its entire content vertically? In the example below, if I add a `label` element the content of the first row flows over the second row.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .ql-container {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .ql-snow {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid #d1d5db;
    }
    
    .ql-editor {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        line-height: 1.42;
        height: 100%;
        outline: none;
        overflow-y: auto;
        padding: 12px 15px;
        -o-tab-size: 4;
        tab-size: 4;
        -moz-tab-size: 4;
        text-align: left;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
  </style>

  </head>
  <body>    
    <div class="container">
        <form class="my-3">
            <div class="row py-2">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="txtBox" class="form-label">Title</label>
                    <div id="txtBox" class="ql-container ql-snow">
                        <div class="ql-editor">
                            <p>TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row py-2">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    next row
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

**Edit 1:**
Smaller example

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .ql-container {
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid #d1d5db;
    }
    
  </style>

  </head>
  <body>    
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    Title
                    <div id="txtBox" class="ql-container">
                            <p>
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            TESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTESTESTTESTE
                            </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    next row
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This overlap is being caused by your style rule:

```
  <style>
    .ql-container {
        height: 100%;
        ...
    }
    
  </style>
```

Along with the html structure:

```
              <div class="col"><!-- this is the parent element -->  

                Title <!-- the height of this text is same as overlap -->

                <div id="txtBox" class="ql-container">
                  <!-- because this element's height is 100% of the parent --> 
                </div>

              </div>
```

If you must have the style rule, for reasons not made apparent in your question, then the solution is to
**Either:** Make a whole new `.row` with `.col` for the text `Title`:

```
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                Title <!-- the height of this text no longer has affect -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col"><!-- this is the parent element --> 
                <div id="txtBox" class="ql-container">
                  <!-- this element's height is 100% of the parent --> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Or:** Just put `Title` in its own `.col-12` forcing subsequent `.col`(s) to wrap to the next line.

```
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                Title <!-- the height of this text no longer has affect -->
              </div>
              <div class="col"><!-- this is the parent element --> 
                <div id="txtBox" class="ql-container">
                  <!-- this element's height is 100% of the parent --> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```